# Remove spaces in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, spaces

I'm new to PHP and I've been searching all day how to do this, but how would I make it so that when a user inputs info into a database

It pulls the data as "blah-bah"

Instead of "Blah Blah"

Comment: What is your input? Can you show us that code sample?

Comment: Well the way I have it is someone puts in a name say for example "My Name" I want to be able to pull the data as "my-name" but and still be able to view it dynamically without adding a new field in my database (if that makes sense lol)

Comment: There is an answer given. What do you think about that. Is that what you want or something else. I didn't understand this part of your comment "but and still be able to view it dynamically without adding a new field in my database" .

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Care to clarify what you *actually* want to do?

Comment: Never mind, I found out what I had to do.

I selected the information where the name equals the variable I put in but with

`strtolower(str_replace('-', ' ', $name))`

As the WHERE part

That makes it so that it selects "My Name" when "my-name" was inputted in the URL

Then that was basically it.

Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', 'Blah Blah'));
```

Comment: regular expression, $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $string);
 if you want to remove more than 1

Comment: `str_replace()` will remove more than one. The benefit of a regular expression is if you wanted to remove additional whitespace (e.g. a tab)

Comment: It depends whether you want to replace all spaces with a dash, or *collapse* continuous whitespace into *one* dash. Your can do the latter with regexen.